# Possible to use subset of AOSP platform codebase?

Tags: android, c++, integration, android-source, platform

I don't know if this question fits with SO's question guidelines.

We are a small media company, that specialises in customising Android to add extra sounds effects to the AOSP platform code. We do this by modifying the AOSP's frameworks/av/media C++ code, and adding Java and resource code to packages/apps/Settings.

We work with several Android phone manufacturers in Asia. The problem that we encounter is that these companies are reluctant to give us a copy of their customised AOSP codebase, which is understandable, given their investment in IP. I was wondering if we could use the standard Google AOSP, plus a subset of the manufacturer's customisations, such as drivers and their precompiled libraries, to allow us to integrate out software locally onto their phone, and test this software locally before on-site integration / acceptance testing. Now we have to perform the integration on-site with no prior preparation, with the resulting last-minute problems and stress.

Is this possible?

Paul

Comment: Can you?  Sure.  AN emulator can run a custom ROM.  How close that will be to the actual end results is a crap shoot though.

Comment: That's the problem, we have to build the ROM in the first place.

Comment: yes it is possible. Since you know exactly where you are doing customization, you can do it with AOSP. Though Initially it will take time to setup a build process.